# LL parser stack states

Tags: parsing, generics, tree, stack

I think that the initial state of LL parser's the stack is 0,but I am not sure about the final, is it empty perhaps? Anyone who could explain this to me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser
It seems that initially the stack is not empty. The final state seems to be empty.

Comment: Since you're not sure of the answer, this belongs as a comment, not an answer. Thank you for taking time to post the link, however.

Comment: Actually I wanted something more precise..I had supposition about this, but thank you anyway.